# Get elements of Json hash table in JS

Tags: javascript, json, hashtable

the problem is [error that i got in chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD4Cu.png)

I just want to have access for these items dynamically with the help of argument of my function

*this is my JS code*

```
function response(name){
    var member = mytable.name;
    console.log(name);
    var resp = name +' is a '+ titul;
    return resp;
}
```

*this is my json hash*

```
mytable = {
    "Anton Buday": {
        "titul": "Phd student",
        "staff_member": "Ing. Anton Buday",
        "translation": "Антон Будай",
        "job_title": "denný doktorand",
        "office": "",
        "building": "BN32",
        "mail": "anton.buday@tuke.sk",
        "landline": "+421 55 602 2298"
    },
    "Gabriel Bugar": {
        "titul": "assistant professor",
        "staff_member": "Ing. Gabriel Bugár, PhD.",
        "translation": "Габріел Бугаар",
        "job_title": "odborný asistent",
        "office": 515,
        "building": "BN32",
        "mail": "gabriel.bugar@tuke.sk",
        "landline": "+421 55 602 2808"
    }
}
```

I already tried it but, the same error occured 
`mytable[name]` 
same error occurred (
thanks everyone for help

Comment: `mytable[name]` ...

Comment: I already tried it but, the same error occured

Comment: The error does not occur in the piece of code youve shown.

Comment: I have tried but i get  the same error, this way  "var titul = mytable[name].titul;
    var resp = name +' is a '+ titul;"